# Center of mass - with polar integration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Can someone give a reference textbook, etc which explains / has examples for polar integration to calculate center of mass.
(This is at the level of advanced pre-college physics, say for example the JEE entrance exam, so references that explain in detail are preferred.

JEE does not have multivariable calculus. Will prefer refernces that use  single integration. Simple shapes will do

Answer (score 3):

In polar coordinates the differential area element is

$$ {\rm d}A = r\, {\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta $$

If the shape is described by the boundary polar curve $R(\theta)$ then the total area is

$$ A = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{R(\theta)} r\,{\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta $$

Also in cartesian coordinates, any point in the shape is described by the coordinates

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{r \cos \theta \\ r \sin \theta} $$

So the center of mass of a uniform thickness shape is found with the following integral

$$ \pmatrix{c_x \\ c_y} = \frac{1}{A} \int \pmatrix{x \\ y} {\rm d}A = \frac{1}{A} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{R(\theta)} r \pmatrix{r \cos \theta \\ r \sin \theta} \,{\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta$$

---

Example of a circular sector, $R(\theta)=R$, but for $\theta = -\tfrac{\psi}{2} \ldots \tfrac{\psi}{2}$

$$ A = \int_{-\psi/2}^{\psi/2} \int_0^{R} r\,{\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta = \frac{\psi}{2} R^2$$

and

$$ \pmatrix{c_x\\c_y} = \frac{1}{A} \int_{-\psi/2}^{\psi/2} \int_0^{R} \pmatrix{r^2 \cos \theta \\ r^2 \sin \theta}\,{\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta = \pmatrix{\tfrac{4 R}{3 \psi} \sin \tfrac{\psi}{2} \\ 0}$$

Comment: I forgot to mention. JEE does not have multivariable calculus. Is it possible to do center of mass with polar integration (but single integration.....). Simple shapes will do.

Comment: @Starlight 1-D shapes need single integration, 2-D shapes need double integrals and so on - you get the idea. Also, double integration isn't too complex - it's basically computing one integral after another one. The important thing is to identify which one must be evaluated first.

Comment: How does a standard reference book for JEE (say Physics Galaxy by Ashish Arora) do it with single variable calculus? Does he skimp the math, or make simplifying assumptions?

Comment: @Starlight - Since [Physics.SE] is not a do my homework type of site, providing an answer beyond the physics concepts shown above, and trying to conform to whatever JEE is (assuming it is a classroom setting) would be in violation of the rules here.

Comment: I am simply trying to understand the concept. JEE is an exam, so I am not asking you to do my homework. Anyway, thanks for the double integration approach.